# Validating multiple entity creation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

The goal here is to allow a user to fill out a timesheet. A single time entity is represented by the following model (simplified):

```
Public Class ppTimeItem
    <Key()>
    Public Property TimeItemID As Integer

    // fields that will be entered only once (global)
    Public Property TaskID As Integer
    Public Property EmployeeID As Integer
    Public Property HourlyRate As Decimal

    // fields that can be entered multiple times (see below)
    Public Property ActivityDate As Date
    Public Property HoursWorked As Decimal
    Public Property Billable As Boolean
    Public Property Notes As String
End Class
```

However, because a user must be able to submit multiple time entities at once, I am using a model with several global fields (something the user only needs to enter once and that will apply to all time entities) and a collection of individual time entities:

```
Public Class TimesheetTaskModel
    // fields that will be applied to every ppTimeItem in the collection
    Public Property TaskID As Integer
    Public Property EmployeeID As Integer
    Public Property HourlyRate As Integer

    Public Property times As IEnumerable(Of ppTimeItem)
End Class
```

This way, a user only needs to enter certain fields once, which will apply to every single time entity in the collection. This is what the timesheet looks like that a user must fill out:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.TaskID)
@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", String.Empty)
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.HourlyRate)

...
<tr>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="times[0].ActivityDate" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="times[0].HoursWorked" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="times[0].Billable" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="times[0].Notes" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="times[1].ActivityDate" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="times[1].HoursWorked" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="times[1].Billable" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="times[1].Notes" /></td>
</tr>
...
```

After filling out the fields and submitting the form, the controller needs to handle the validation. This is where I am a little stuck. Normally with a single entity, I can just call something like...

```
<HttpPost()>
Function CreateEntity(ent As TheEntity) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        // Add single entity to database
        // Save database changes
        // Return Redirect
    Else
        // Return View(ent)
    End If
End Function
```

... where on failed validation, the entity is simply returned back to the view, all fields that were previously entered are still displayed, and all validation errors are highlighted in red. Simple defaults.

With multiple entity creation this doesn't work. When I return the `TimesheetTaskModel` back to the view, none of the previously entered fields are saved and no validation errors are shown. How can I validate each time entity? I'm really looking for something along the lines of...

```
<HttpPost()>
Function CreateTimeItems(ttm As TimesheetTaskModel) As ActionResult
    For Each ti as ppTimeItem in ttm.times
        // If ti does not have valid model state
            // Return View(ttm)  <-- Needs to show errors
        // End If

        // If all items had valid model state, add each to the database
    Next
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you simply tried `Return View()` in your action ? You don't need to pass your model, because your form will be filled by the `ModelState`

Comment: @RédaMattar Just tried that, same results where it doesn't fill in the form or validate any fields.

Comment: Do you have a validation summary on your view? Can you verify in the controller that there are errors in the ModelState?

Comment: No I do not have a validation summary on the view. But yes, there are ModelState errors whenever the date/hours fields are left blank or if invalid numbers are entered.